# PHP Ajax multiple file upload timeout or memory limit

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, file-upload

I have the following in my php.ini

```
    post_max_size = 400M
    upload_max_filesize = 400M
    max_file_uploads = 200
    memory_limit = 400M
    max_execution_time = 259200
    max_input_time = 259200
    session.gc_maxlifetime = 1200
```

I use Jquery Ajax to upload multiple files dynamically. Images are converted to JPG and uploaded. For some reason, there is a timeout or memory limit. I check phpinfo() and all the above are set. Is there a way to get an error response for my upload. Or is there a timeout inside the Ajax. The problem I believe lies in part right after the temporary files are uploaded. I have a progress bar, it goes to 100%, then it doesn't run any upload script as it should. Any ideas? What else to add or do. I can't upload beyond 30 seconds or 10+ MB. Thanks

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: My first reaction: there is no reason to send multiple files at once; send them one by one, problem solved.  I'm interested to see the code you use to upload with AJAX.  By the way, do you resize the images before uploading?

Answer (score 1):

My mistake, the php.ini was only in the directory of the user page, but it was missing in the folder where the ajax sends the request to post. Note: put php.ini where ever there is a script running for the upload or change it throughout the entire site with .htaccess.